# Can we improve advice to those asking questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Quite a few questions asked generate comments that the OP doesn't answer.

Let me suggest adding a bit to the Help Center advice on asking questions to say that responding to such comments will likely improve both the number and quality of answers. A short paragraph in one of the existing points is probably enough.

Timeliness of a response can also help the flow. This might be part of an update.

I find myself wanting to say this to the OP fairly frequently but also want to avoid cluttering up the comment stream.

Comment: Where do you suggest to put this advice and will it be specific to this site? Mind that the only help-centre site we can edit is [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, in Final Remarks would work.  Or a new heading.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, I've added an answer with some suggested text for that page.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft and other mods. Is there any chance this can be made to happen? If so, when?

Answer (score 8):

What follows is suggested text to be added to [this page](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which is under the control of this site. I may have to edit it a few times and you should feel free to do so also. I think the addition could come just before Final Remarks:

---

#### Follow up your question.

Questions asked often generate comments asking for additional information. The comments can come quite quickly as there are a lot of users here.

It is advisable to respond to such comments, preferably by [editing your question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) to add the additional information. You can also add [comments of your own](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) but that is less useful as comments can disappear. Responding and making your question more complete will improve both the likelihood of answers and their quality. Some users will wait to answer until you respond in some way.

Eventually, you may want to [accept](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one of the answers that you find especially valuable. It is suggested that you wait a bit (days, at least) before doing so as some users hesitate to answer questions with accepted answers.

Comment: There are quite a number of new users who don't know how to edit the question or how to write comments. We might need to point them to where to learn how to edit the question and how to write comments.

Comment: @Nobody, there could be screenshots showing them how to do it under this explanation. After all, its just a button you need to click.

Comment: @Sursula, and Nobody, I've added links to relevant pages for commenting and editing.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, see the edits. Enough?

Comment: Looks good, thanks!